# Young inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

I am trying to prove young's inequality for integrals
$$
ab \leq \int\nolimits_0^a \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^b \! f^{-1}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Can you help me please?

Comment: This isn't true in general. Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions) gives the assumptions under which it holds, and the image in that article suggests a proof. (Also I think putting the $-1$ in parentheses is unusual; it looks a bit as if you're trying to denote the reciprocal instead of the inverse.)

Comment: @joriki: the parentheses might have been my fault. I had fixed the tex code. Will remove them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a couple of short proofs in the [Journal of Inequalities in Pure and
Applied Mathematics](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/289_06_JIPAM/289_06_www.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can find some proofs here:

- http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/ElmerTolsted.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A nice presentation is given in the classic book Introduction to Inequalities, by Beckenbach and Bellman. I have cited this book in detail in answer to another question about inequalities elsewhere on this site. Here is the link:
[Geometric mean never exceeds arithmetic mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/geometric-mean-never-exceeds-arithmetic-mean/36274#36274)

Regards,
Mike Jones