# Geometric mean never exceeds arithmetic mean

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, statistics, inequality, induction

This was a mathematical induction question proposed in a textbook, and I've exhausted multiple approaches (proving RHS - LHS > 0, splitting the fraction, fractional exponents, etc.)

> The geometric mean of $n$ positive numbers $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n$ is $\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2 \ldots a_n}$ and their arithmetic mean is $\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}{n}$. If $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are $n$ positive real numbers, prove by induction that their geometric mean is always smaller than or equal to their arithmetic mean, i.e. $\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\ldots a_n} \leq \frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}{n}$

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but the Lagrange multipliers proof is pretty slick. Just take the geometric mean as the function to minimize and the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n$.

Comment: For a big list, see [Proofs of AM-GM inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using induction:

1. Show the base case $n = 2$.
2. Show that if the statement is true for $2^n$, then it is true for $2^{n+1}$.
3. Show that if the statement is true for $n$, then it is true for $n - 1$.

(This method of induction is sometimes called [Cauchy induction](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Cauchy_Induction)).

Comment: Assuming true for $2^{k}$ and attempting to prove true for $2^{k+1}$, I end up with the inequality, $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_k + a_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}} \geq \frac{1}{2}\Big((a_1a_2\ldots a_k)^{\frac{1}{2^k}}+\frac{a_{k+1}}{2^k}\Big)$  but, I have no idea how to proceed next, to reduce the RHS to $(a_1a_2\ldots a_{k+1})^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}$?

Comment: @Jaydon: Your indices seem to be wrong. You need to be finding the means of the terms $a_1$ through $a_{2^{k+1}}$, not $a_{k+1}$. In order to show the $2^{k+1}$ case, try taking the means of the means of $a_1,\ldots,a_{2^k}$ and $a_{2^k+1},\ldots,a_{2^{k+1}}$.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Alex: I don't really understand what you mean by your suggestion to take the "means of the means" and which terms to apply that to. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Jaydon: take $mean(mean(a_0,\ldots,a_{2^k}),mean(a_{2^k+1},\ldots,a_{2^{k+1}}))$ using the arithmetic and geometric means and compare them.

Comment: Which is in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/190518/8271)

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  For induction, you need to prove the base case: $\sqrt{a_1+a_2} \le \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$.  If you square both sides...  Then you need to prove that if it works for $n$ numbers, it works for $n+1$, so put the averages for $a_1 \ldots a_n$ in for $a_1$.

Answer (score 5):

An induction proof which I like, is to prove that

> If $\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n} a_j = 1$ then $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j \ge n$

Now for the induction step, if $\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n+1} a_j = 1$, pick $\displaystyle a_r$ and $\displaystyle a_s$ such that $\displaystyle  0 \ge (1-a_r)(1-a_s)$ and...

For a different proof, one could claim that using the concavity of $\displaystyle \log x$ is an induction proof too (going from $\displaystyle t + (1-t) = 1$ to $\displaystyle t_1 + t_2 + \dots + t_n = 1$).

Comment: Nice proof! That's why the Apostol book Vol 1 listed the I-4.10 Exercise 19 immediate before Exercise 20. We just set $b_i = \frac {a_i} { ( \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i ) ^ {1/n} }$, then we can use the lemma.

Answer (score 4):

Awwh, come on, folks. There are 12 (yes, 12) proofs of the GM-AM Inequality in the classic little book on inequalities by Beckenbach and Bellman.

Here is an excerpt from a reader’s review of the book at Amazon:

> An Introduction to Inequalities is an unexpectedly delightful book.
>   Relatively brief, only 129 pages, this publication of The Mathematical
>   Association of America, requires no more than basic high school
>   mathematics. Nonetheless, I am convinced that Edwin Beckenbach's and
>   Richard Bellman's systematic study of inequalities would interest most
>   students in an early calculus course.
>   …
>   Some classical inequalities were familiar, like the arithmetic mean -
>   geometric mean inequality and the Cauchy inequality (two-dimensional
>   version). But others like the n-dimensional version of the Cauchy
>   inequality (along with the Cauchy-Lagrange identity), the Hölder
>   inequality, and the Minkowski inequality were new to me. What I
>   found most surprising was how these classical inequalities were so
>   interrelated, and how some can be considered generalizations of others.
>   Beckenbach and Bellman introduce clever substitutions to transform one
>   inequality expression into another.

(credit: The reviewer quoted is Michael Wischmeyer, of Houston, Texas.)
[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0394015592) is the link.

There is an old joke that says that sometimes a couple of months spent in the laboratory can save a couple of hours spent in the library.

In other words, let’s refrain from re-inventing the wheel, except purely as an exercise.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Following JavaMan's hint, I came up with the following :

Let the statement$\:\:P(\eta)\equiv\large\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^\eta\:{\normalsize a_j}\:\geq\:\large\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta\sqrt[\large \eta] {\normalsize a_j}$ $\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\eta=2^j,\:\:j\in\mathbb{N}$

Now, $\:P(1)\equiv\large\frac{(a_1+a_2)}{2}$$\:\geq\:\sqrt {a_1a_2}\:\:\longleftrightarrow \:\:a_1-\small2$$\sqrt {a_1a_2}+a_2\:\geq\:0\:\:\longleftrightarrow \:\:\left(\sqrt {a_1}-\sqrt {a_2}\right)^2\:\geq\:0$
wich is certainly true.

Let suppose that$\:P(\eta)\:$holds$\:\forall\eta\:$and let's go and show that it also holds for $\:P(\eta+1)\:$

We have$\:\:2\eta=2^{j+1}\:\:\to \:\:\:\large\frac{1}{2\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{2\eta}\:{\normalsize a_j}=\large\frac{1}{2\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{\eta} \:{\normalsize a_j}\:\:+\:\:\large\frac{1}{2\eta}\sum_\limits{j=\eta +1}^{2\eta} \:\normalsize {a_j} \:\:\:$and,

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\large\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta\:\sqrt[\large 2\eta] {\normalsize a_j}=\sqrt {\large\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta \sqrt[\large \eta] {\normalsize a_j}\:\:\large\prod_\limits{j=\eta +1}^{2\eta} \sqrt[\large \eta] {\normalsize a_j}}\:\:$.

If $\:a_j\leq\large\frac{d}{da_j}$$(a_j)\:\:\forall j\:\:$then,$\:\:\large\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^\eta\:\normalsize {a_j}$$\:\leq\:\large\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^\eta\:\frac{d}{da_j}(\normalsize a_j)\:\:$and$\:\:\large\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta\sqrt[\large \eta] {\normalsize a_j}$$\:\leq\:\large\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta\frac{d}{da_j}(\sqrt[\large \eta]{\normalsize {a_j}})\:$

Therefore, by letting$\:\:\large\Psi_{\eta_1}\:$$=\large\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{\eta}\:\normalsize a_j\:$,$\large\:\:\Phi_{\eta_1}=\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta\sqrt[\large \eta] {\normalsize a_j} \:\:$we have . . .

$\large\Psi_{2\eta_1}=\Psi\left(\Psi_{\eta _1},\Psi_{2\eta _{\eta +1}}\right)$$\:\geq\:$$\large\Psi\left(\Phi_{\eta_1},\Phi_{2\eta_{\eta+1}}\right)$$\:\geq\:$$\large\Phi\left(\Phi_{{\eta_1}},\Phi_{2\eta_{\eta+1}}\right)=\large\Phi_{2\eta_1}$

This proves that $\:\large\Psi$$\:\geq\:$$\large\Phi\:\:$when$\:\eta\:$is a power of$\:\:2$.

$\\$

Now, if $\:\nexists j\:\:$such that $\:\eta=2^j\:$, then we let $\:\omega=\kappa^j\:\:$such that$\:\:\kappa>2,\:\:$and we let every term of the sequence
$\:\large\{$$a_j\large\}$$_{ _{\large{\eta +1}}}^{ ^{\Large\omega}}=\large\Psi_{\eta_1}\:\:\:\:\normalsize \to \:\:...$

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\left(\frac{\LARGE\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta \Large a_j}{\Large\Psi_{\eta_1}^{\omega + \eta}}\right)^{\LARGE\frac{1}{\omega}}\leq\:\large\Psi_{\omega_1} \normalsize ,\:\:\:\:$ since $\large\omega\:$is a power of $\:2\:$

Because$\:\:\large\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^\omega\:{\normalsize a_j}=\large\Psi_{\eta_1}$, it follows that$\:\left(\large\Psi_{\omega_1}\right)^{\large\frac{1}{\omega}}\cdot \left(\large\Psi_{\eta_1}\right)^{{\large1-\frac{\eta}{\omega}}}\leq\:\left(\large\Psi_{\eta_1}\right)^{{\large-\frac{\eta}{\omega}}}$

Then, by putting both sides of the last inequality at the $\:(\large\frac{\omega}{\eta})^{th}\:$power yields :

$\:\large\prod_\limits{j=1}^\eta\sqrt[\large \eta] {\normalsize a_j}\:\leq\:\large\frac{1}{\eta}\sum_\limits{j=1}^\eta\:{\normalsize a_j}$

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\Large\clubsuit$