# Question over induction, suppose $P(n)$ is true for all positive integers $n$ that is a power of 2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Suppose, that $P(k+1) \Rightarrow P(k)$ for all positive integers $k$. How would I prove $P(n)$ is true?

I am getting confused since this is going the 'other way'. Usually $P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)$

Comment: For a non-speculative answer, you should state the full problem. There *are* instances of "downward" induction.

Comment: Hi André, this is the full problem. Would there be a generalized way to prove "downward" induction?

Comment: I had not noticed that you had put part of the question in the long title.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97350/how-does-backwards-induction-work-to-prove-a-property-for-all-naturals and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190518/induction-proof-s-contains-powers-of-2-and-predecessors-implies-s-bf-n (You can find more related questions among linked questions there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P(n)$ is sometimes false, let $a$ be a positive integer such that $P(a)$ is false. Let $2^n$ be the smallest power of $2$ (or any power of $2$) which is $\ge a$. Let $k$ be the largest positive integer $\le 2^n$ such that $P(k)$ is false. Note that $k\lt 2^n$.

It follows that $P(k+1)$ is true, which implies that $P(k)$ is true, and we have reached a contradiction.