# AM/GM mean for $n=3$ using $n=4$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Suppose I know that $\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\ge(abcd)^\frac{1}{4}$ for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d \in \mathbb{R^+}$

How can I show that $\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge(xyz)^\frac{1}{3}$ for $x$, $y$, $z \in \mathbb{R^+}$

My first guess was to let $d=1$ and go from there but that didn't work out. Any tips?

Comment: Take $a=x,b=y,c=z$ and $d=(x+y+z)/3$.

Comment: For the general case, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739804/how-to-understand-cauchys-proof-of-am-gm-inequalitythe-last-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set $d=\sqrt[3]{abc}$. Then, an easy calculation shows $\sqrt[4]{abcd}=\sqrt[4]{d^3\cdot d}=d=\sqrt[3]{abc}$, and from $$\frac{a+b+c+\sqrt[3]{abc}}4\ge\sqrt[3]{abc}$$ follows immediately $$\frac{a+b+c}3\ge\sqrt[3]{abc}.$$