# AM-GM inequality in $3$ variables

Tags: proof-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to prove AM-GM inequality in $3$ variables.

> Prove that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \ge 3abc$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Could you please verify if my attempt contains logical gaps/errors?

---

**My attempt:**

*Lemma:* $a^2 + b^2 \ge 2ab$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

It follows from our lemma that $a^3 + b^3 \ge 2 \sqrt{a^3b^3} = 2ab\sqrt{ab}$ and $c^3 +abc \ge 2\sqrt{c^4ab} = 2c^2 \sqrt{ab}$, and that $ab\sqrt{ab} + c^2 \sqrt{ab} \ge 2\sqrt{ab\sqrt{ab}c^2 \sqrt{ab}} = 2abc$.

As a result, $(a^3 + b^3) + (c^3 +abc) \ge 2ab\sqrt{ab} + 2c^2 \sqrt{ab} \ge 4abc$ and so $a^3 +b^3 +c^3 \ge 3abc$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Better is to use that $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc= \left( a+b+c \right)  \left( {a}^{2}-ab-ac+{b}^{2}-bc+{c}^{2}
 \right) 
$$

Comment: Could you expand on that? Sorry I am a bit of a novice and just starting out.

Comment: See here https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Proofs_of_AM-GM

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739804/how-to-understand-cauchys-proof-of-am-gm-inequalitythe-last-step