# AM-GM inequality in $n$ variables

Tags: proof-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> For all $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in [\mathbb{R}^+]^n$, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n a^n_i \ge n \prod_{i=1}^n a_i$$

I posted a question about AM-GM inequality in $3$ variables [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275555/am-gm-inequality-in-3-variables). After that, I found that I can utilize the same method to generalize this inequality to arbitrary $n$ variables.

Could you please verify if my attempt contains logical gaps/errors?

---

**My attempt:**

We prove this statement by induction on $n$. Clearly, it holds for $n = 1$. Let it hold for $n$. We have

$$\begin{aligned}
&\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a^{n+1}_i \right ) + (n-1)\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i \\
= &  \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{n+1}_i \right ) + \left ( a_{n+1}^{n+1}  + \underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i  + \ldots \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i}_{(n-1) \text{ times}} \right ) \\
\ge & n \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{n+1}} + n \sqrt[n]{a_{n+1}^{n+1} \left (\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i \right )^{n-1}} \quad \text{ by inductive hypothesis}\\
= & n \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{n+1}} + n \sqrt[n]{a_{n+1}^{n+1} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i^{n-1}} \\
= &n \left (2 \sqrt[2]{\sqrt[n]{\left ( \prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{n+1} \right ) a_{n+1}^{n+1} \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i^{n-1} }} \right )\\
= & 2n \sqrt[2]{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i^{2n}}} \\
= & 2n \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i
\end{aligned}$$

It follows that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a^{n+1}_i \ge [2n - (n-1)] \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i = (n+1) \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i$$

Then the statement holds for $n+1$. This completes the proof.

Comment: For the first batch of equalities/inequalities, the third equality should be an inequality: it appears you're doing AM-GM with $n=2$.

Comment: Actually, since you're using AM-GM with $n=2$ there, your base case for the induction should be $n=2$.

Comment: Thank you so much @mathworker21. You are totally correct.

Comment: Otherwise, great proof!