# Prove Nesbitt's inequality to a layman

Tags: inequality

I've been playing around with Nesbitt's inequality and I can see that it must be true.

Nesbitt's inequality states that for positive real numbers
$a$, $b$, and $c$:

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} \geq \frac{3}{2}$$

I'm a leyman and saw some proofs using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the Jensen's inequality but I don't understand those. Is there any easier way?

Comment: The short answer is yes. I saw such a proof in the first few pages the book “Inequalities” by Cvetkovski. The proof isn’t super obvious though.

Comment: There are nine different proofs in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality

Comment: See the third proof in the Wikipedia page. Hint: if your question has an answer that is easy to find googling or in Wikipedia, expect to receive downvotes.

Comment: It would be more constructive if you tell us what proofs you have seen and what you do not understand about them. Otherwise there is a high risk that another proof presented here will also not satisfy you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are many way to prove Nesbitt's ineqality. I hope this one works for you.

From Nesbitt's inequality it directly follows that
$$\frac{a^3 + a^2 b + a^2 c + a b^2 + 3 a b c + a c^2 + b^3 + b^2 c + b c^2 + c^3}{(a + b) (a + c) (b + c)} \geq \frac{3}{2}$$
And by clearing denominators we get
$$2(a^3 + a^2 b + a^2 c + a b^2 + 3 a b c + a c^2 + b^3 + b^2 c + b c^2 + c^3) \\ \geq 3(a^2 b + a^2 c + a b^2 + 2 a b c + a c^2 + b^2 c + b c^2)$$
This holds if and only if
$$2 a^3 + 2 b^3 + 2 c^3 \geq a^2 b + a^2 c + a b^2 + a c^2 + b^2 c + b c^2\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }(\star)$$
By Cauchy's Inequality (AM-GM) we have
$$\begin{equation}
    \frac{a^3 + a^3 + b^3}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{a^3 a^3 b^3} = a^2 b
\end{equation}$$
Using this it follows
$$\begin{align*}
    2 a^3 &+ 2 b^3 + 2 c^3  \\
    &= \frac{a^3 + a^3 + b^3}{3} + \frac{a^3 + a^3 + c^3}{3} + \frac{a^3 + b^3 + b^3}{3} \\
&+ \frac{a^3 + c^3 + c^3}{3} + \frac{b^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3}  + \frac{b^3 + c^3 + c^3}{3} \\
    &\geq a^2 b + a^2 c + a b^2 + a c^2 + b^2 c + b c^2
\end{align*}$$
This proves $(\star)$ and thus the desired Nesbitt's inequality.

Comment: What does (AM-GM) mean?

Comment: @BroBiden Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739804/how-to-understand-cauchys-proof-of-am-gm-inequalitythe-last-step#739867)

Comment: *“From Nesbitt's inequality it directly follows that ...”* is the wrong start if you want to *prove* that inequality.