# A sequence of integers with infinitely many positive and infinitely many negative integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

$\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of integers such that there are infinitely many positive as well as infinitely many negative integers in the sequence. Let for each $r$,
the remainders of $a_1, \dots , a_r\bmod r$ are distinct. Then I need to show that every integer occurs
exactly once in the sequence. I don't know in which direction to proceed. Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but ... Where is this question coming from? - What is its background? (Some research? A math competition of some sort?) Just curious...

Comment: Hint: show $\,a_1,\ldots, a_N\,$ forms a *consecutive* sequence of $N$ integers (when reordered), by noting that if any elements differed by $\,\color{#c00}K\ge N\,$ then two remainders would be equal in $\,a_1,\ldots, a_{\color{#c00}K}\ \ $

Comment: And, [of course](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190543/242) $\Bbb Z\,$ is the only consecutive sequence of integers that has has no lower or upper bound.