# Arithmetic Mean And Geometric Mean

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $A.M$ and $G.M$ are Arithmetic Mean And Geometric Mean respectively then prove that $A.M \ge G.M$.

My Attempt :

Let $a$ and $b$ are any two real positive numbers. 
Then:
 $$A.M=\frac{a+b}{2}$$

$$G.M =\sqrt{ab} $$

Now how can we show that $A.M.\ge G.M.$ ? Please help me..

Comment: Hint: $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$

Comment: See the answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/geometric-mean-never-exceeds-arithmetic-mean?rq=1

Comment: A duplicate of [this old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64881/269624) actually

Answer (score 2):

$$0\leq\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)^{2}=a+b-2\sqrt{ab}.$$

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more? I can't understand

Comment: @user335710 A squared number is always greater or equal than $0$. About the equality see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_(polynomial)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let $AF=a, FB=b$. We construct the semicircle with diameter $AB$. Then $$DE=\frac{a+b}2; CF=\sqrt{ab}$$
$$DE\ge CF \Rightarrow \frac{a+b}2\ge\sqrt{ab}$$

Answer (score 0):

Extending Marco Cantarini's answer
$$0\leq\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)^{2}
=a+b-2\sqrt{ab}
=> 0\leq a+b-2\sqrt{ab}
=> 2\sqrt{ab}\leq a+b
=>  \sqrt{ab}\leq\frac{a+b}{2}
=> G.M.\leq A.M.$$