# How to show $(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How to show $(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}$ with $a_i$ positive.

Well, I tried by induction: with $n=2$ then $\sqrt{ab}\leq \frac{a+b}{2}$ is equivalent to say (elevate square in both side) $4ab\leq a^2 +2ab + b^2$ and this is equivalent $0\leq(a-b)^2$ and this is true.

I suppose it is true for some $n$. But with $n+1$, I don't know how to do, Please can help me with a hint or other way, thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proofs of AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality)

Comment: Among the proofs at @Fractal's link, perhaps the simplest proof by induction is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1665056); that one's not famous enough. marty cohen's link contains it too, [in much less detail](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple proof which doesn't require induction (except implicitly); compare the logarithms. You only need to show that
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\ln a_i}n\le\ln\frac{\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\bigr)}n, $$
and this results from $\ln$ being a concave function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple proof based on a very nice result here [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), which is very useful in many areas (mathematics, economics, etc).

to understand this result, it suffices to know simple things about convex functions in one variable at the level of High school or first year college Calculus.